# Book title; mission to moon in which 3 crew & ship are pursued by aliens & thrown back in time

Tags: story-identification

looking for title of 1950's / 1960's adventure concerning mission to moon in which 3 crew & ship are pursued by aliens & thrown back in time to prehistoric Earth;  there the crew encounter aliens again living in domes.  I can only remember one character, Mitch, the Australian engineer.

Answer (score 7):

You've described [Journey Into Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_into_Space), which was a BBC radio show from the 1950s, which meets pretty much all your criteria. There was a [novelization](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?398801), which I was unaware of until I started researching the answer; but I am very familiar with the radio show.

The first season, Operation Luna, has a four man crew making the first landing on the Moon; while there, they're sent back in time and meet aliens who have colonized a prehistoric Earth. As well as Mitch, the Australian engineer, there's also "Jet" Morgan, the Captain; "Doc", the - er - doctor; and Lemmy, the radio operator (who doesn't seem to know much about rocket ships, and so ends up having things explained to him, and therefore the audience.)

There were two further series made, The Red Planet (involving a trip to Mars) and The World In Peril (a direct sequel to The Red Planet); there were also various specials and spin offs made by the BBC over the decades.

The CDs of the show are available (and are well worth a listen); it's also played on BBC Radio 4 Extra every year or so.